# Localization of Custom Controls in a redistributable assembly

Tags: asp.net, localization, .net-assembly, web-deployment-project, app-globalresources

I'm trying to build a redistributable assembly containing several custom controls (*CommonControls*).
**My environment: MSVC 2010, ASP.NET (WebForms) .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5**

The problem: Compiling everything with a **Web Deployment Project** won't work if I localize *CommonControls* via **App_GlobalResources**.

Here is how I build the *CommonControls* assembly:

I use a WebSite containing the .ascx and .ascx.cs files:

[image: Solution explorer]

and a **Web Deployment Project** with the following settings:

[image: Web Deployment Project settings (CommonControls)]

This will create "CommonControls.dll".
That assembly is to be used in a different ASP.NET WebApplication as follows:

web.config:
[image: web.config]

First (minor) problem: Adding *CommonControls* as a dependency will not automatically copy the satellite assemblies for the languages. Copying them manually to the correct output path seems to work though (for DEBUGGING).

Main problem: The *Main* web application is also localized via **App_GlobalResources** and built with a **Web Deployment Project**:

[image: Web Deployment Project settings ("Main")]

That build process will fail with

> ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Both deployment projects create a file named "bin\App_GlobalResources.compiled" and I guess those 2 files cannot coexist peacefully within the same output-project.

Is there any elegant solution to localize both *CommonContols* AND *Main* using ASP.NET built-in localization?

Note: The project I'm working on has to be compatible with Apache+Mono, so my project-settings (screenshots above) must be exactly like this to work correctly (already tested all other variations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It was (probably) caused by outdated assemblies in the Bin folder used by the WDP (seems to be a good idea to manually clean that folder from time to time).

I also copied files from "CommonControls\Bin" to the final output (via pre-build event) which is not necessary and causes everything to break (satellite assemblies for translations are automatically copied by MSVC).

While my problem+solution might not be that helpful to others, it's at least a tutorial how to build a re-distributable assembly with some custom-controls out of a bunch of user-controls.

Notes:

- All outputs of the custom-control assembly must be merged. Otherwise we will end up with 2 "App_GlobalResources.dll" files (won't work)
- It only works with a "Web-site project", not "Web application"
- User-controls must use the "CodeFile/Inherit" tags, not the deprecated "CodeBehind" tag (get rid of all those ".designer.cs" files!)
- User-controls must have a "ClassName" tag that differs from the control's name (I appended "Internal" and renamed the class(es) in code-behind)
- Embedded resources (images, scripts...) are not directly supported in a "Web-site project". I use an additional LIB for that